# Unable to access login page in Golang

Tags: go

I am new to Golang. I have made a demo app for practice in which i have login register and homepage. When i go to login page it redirects to home page . I am not understanding what is happening.

This is my go code

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

var db *sql.DB
var err error

func signupPage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("entered Signup")
    if req.Method != "POST" {
        http.ServeFile(res, req, "template/signup.html")
        return
    }

    email := req.FormValue("email")
    password := req.FormValue("password")

    var user string

    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?", email).Scan(&user)

    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, "Server error, unable to create your account.", 500)
            return
        }

        _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO users(email, password) VALUES(?, ?)", email, hashedPassword)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, "Server error, unable to create your account.", 500)
        }
        res.Write([]byte("User Registered Successfully"))
        return

    case err != nil:
        http.Error(res, "Server error, unable to create your account.", 500)
        return

    default:
        http.Redirect(res, req, "/", 301)
    }

}

func loginPage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Entered login")
    if req.Method != "POST" {
        http.ServeFile(res, req, "template/login.html")
        return
    }

    email := req.FormValue("email")
    password := req.FormValue("password")

    var dbemail string
    var dbpassword string

    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT email, password FORM users WHERE email=?", email).Scan(&dbemail, &dbpassword)
    if err != nil {
        http.Redirect(res, req, "/login", 301)
        return
    }

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(dbpassword), []byte(password))
    if err != nil {
        http.Redirect(res, req, "/login", 301)
        return
    }

    res.Write([]byte("Hello" + dbemail))

}

func homePage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(res, req, "template/landing.html")
}

func main() {
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@/golang_demo")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Database connected successfully")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/login", loginPage)
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/signup", signupPage)

    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}
```

When i go to signup page it goes successfully. But when i go to login page it is redirecting me to home page. Please help!

Comment: try moving     http.HandleFunc("/login", loginPage) after the     http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)

Comment: @matiit I tried all that stuff still i am not getting any thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an educated guess, since from the code I am seeing it doesn't look like that should happen.  Since you are using `301` redirects (Moved Permanently), I would guess that at *some point* in writing your function and testing it, you did a redirect to the home page.  Since it is "moved permanently", the browser now doesn't even ask the server if it should redirect when it sees that URL, it just does it.

If you're in chrome, open the dev tools, and disabling the cache should resolve it.  Or even better, try it in a different browser that you haven't used on this site yet, and see if it works there.